# javascript google map api v3 not showing on android

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-maps

i have this little function to call google map v3

```
function showMap(con, lat, lon, name) {
    con = $(con); if (con.length<1) return;
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    if (ua.indexOf('iPhone') != -1 || ua.indexOf('Android') != -1 ) con.css('height','100%');
    else con.css('height','400px');

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);
    var opt = {
        zoom:14, center:latlng,
        mapTypeControl:false, navigationControlOptions:{style:google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(con.get(0), opt);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position:latlng, map:map, title:name });
    con.show();
}
```

my problem is the map appears in chrome, firefox (desktop) but not in android. any suggestion?

EDIT: It working now. apparently my div container was hidden initially, so i move .show() to top before creating the map.

Comment: Are you using this JavaScript code inside a WebView, or are you using a platform such as Phonegap/Cordova, or is this meant to run inside a browser when you visit a website?

Comment: it's a mobile aware website (bootstrap+jquery), meant to run inside a browser. i found this site http://html5demos.com/geo run similar code perfectly fine on android.